# MS DOS function like ipconfig to get system performance specs?

Tags: system, specifications, msinfo32

I am aware of MSINFO32, but I'm wondering if there is a MS DOS command similar to ipconfig in order to get system specifications?

I would like for the system specifications to be displayed in the MS DOS prompt.

I would like to see at least:
CPU
RAM
BUS speed

Thanks for any insights.

Edit: I am unable to install any other software, so just have to use existing DOS programming commands to extract this information.  Thank you again.

2nd Edit:  Whoops. Using Windows XP and Windows Vista.

Comment: Are you sure that this is programming-related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WMIC`. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx)  for more info. There's a [tonne of info](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wmic) about it on SO too.

Comment: Is this installed by default?

Comment: You need to be specific about what OSes you need to support.  I have it on XP.